# Oracle Apex Error on pages with image upload options : Request protocol is https

Tags: oracle-apex

I have apex application with page where i have image upload option set using mimetype/filetype functionality.

The page also has another region which displays the images in a classic report column.

I am able to upload images and they are getting saved in database as well.

However on the page, there is always an error in the dev toolbar below.
In view debug the error comes as:

```
Request protocol is https: can only set caching headers for get
```

What could be the reason for this?

Apex version is 20.1